# In what conditions every ideal is an extension ideal? Is every prime ideal extension of prime ideal?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals, ideals

Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings (with $1$), and $f : R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism. For an ideal $I$ of $R$, set $I^e:=\langle f(I)S\rangle$ (called the extension of $I$ to $S$). When $f$ is *surjective*, every ideal, $J$, of $S$ is an extension ideal; i.e. $J=I^e$, for some ideal $I$ of $R$.

> Question 1. What other (non-trivial) conditions can be posed on rings or the homomorphism to have every ideal of $S$ be an extension ideal? Is there *special rings and homomorphism* that we have this property? ( By "special rings and homomorphism", I mean the cases like $f : R\to R[X]$)

---

Question 2. In the case of "Question 1", (every ideal of $S$ an extension ideal), can one say that

> "If $Q$ is a prime ideal of $S$, then there is a *prime* ideal, $P$, of $R$, such that $P^e=Q$?"

Thank you.

Comment: I also asked this at [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314266/in-what-conditions-every-ideal-is-an-extension-ideal), a few days ago

Answer (score 2):

A localization is another example, see [Tag 02C9](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02C9). If an ideal $J \subset S$ is an extension ideal, say $J = IS$ for $I \subset R$ an ideal, then
we see that $J = f^{-1}(J) S$. If you apply this to a prime ideal, then you get the answer to Question 2.

Comment: thank you+ do you have any idea about Question 1, in general?